# Using formulas/VBA for parsing a length-delimited CSV file into 140 columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

At my work I have to do a weekly job of cleaning up a raw data file so it matches a specific form.

The data comes in a CSV file so that all the data for one record is on one row. 
What the CSV looks like:

- Each record (row) has to be split into 140 columns.
- There can be over 20,000 rows in one CSV.
- The file is not delimited by a symbol, but rather each column is a
  specific number of characters into the row data string with a
  specific length.
- The assigned space for columns is not constant. A last name column is
  longer than a product code column.
- We also need to change the formatting of some columns after
  importing. That's why in the code portion I have "00"+ for data(1). I
  plan on adding more of them later if I get the code to work
  reasonably fast.

What has been used so far is a simple method where we dump the CSV file contents into the first column of Sheet1, then the formulas in Sheet2 use mid() function to parse through the 20,000+ rows of data and split it into columns. (Ex: =MID(Sheet1!$A1,B$1,B$2) , where B$1 and B$2 contain the specific location and length for this column)

However, because the Sheet2 is practically completely full of the mid() formula, the filesize is over 50 mb. This makes the Workbook slow to work with and it has been known to crash with large files.

To me, a better way of parsing through the rows would be with VBA. However, I attempted to create an array loop that would parse through one row, put the values to Sheet2 and then loop until all rows are done. The code works, but it when I tried it with 23,943 rows of data, it locked up my computer for a good 11 minutes.

So the question is: am I stuck using the formulas, is there something wrong with my code or is there a working way of parsing through this?

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Attempt2()

Dim Data(1 To 140) As Variant
Dim shSource As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim location As Integer
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer


LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For Rows = 1 To LastRow

'Set the source cell that is being parsed

Set shSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows, 1)

'Array picks up all 140 values

Data(1) = "00" + Mid(shSource, 1, 2)
Data(2) = Mid(shSource, 3, 9)
Data(3) = Mid(shSource, 12, 16)
Data(4) = Mid(shSource, 28, 12)
Data(5) = Mid(shSource, 40, 1)
Data(6) = Mid(shSource, 41, 35)
Data(7) = Mid(shSource, 76, 19)
Data(8) = Mid(shSource, 95, 2)
Data(9) = Mid(shSource, 97, 5)
Data(10) = Mid(shSource, 102, 4)
Data(11) = Mid(shSource, 106, 8)
Data(12) = Mid(shSource, 114, 5)
Data(13) = Mid(shSource, 120, 5)
Data(14) = Mid(shSource, 125, 5)

location = 130


For i = 15 To 113

    Data(i) = Mid(shSource, location, 6)
    location = location + 6

Next i

Data(114) = Mid(shSource, 724, 3)
location = location + 3

For i = 115 To 118
    Data(i) = Mid(shSource, location, 6)
    location = location + 6

Next i

Data(119) = Mid(shSource, 751, 3)
location = location + 3

For i = 120 To 123
    Data(i) = Mid(shSource, location, 6)
    location = location + 6

Next i

Data(124) = Mid(shSource, 778, 3)
location = location + 3

For i = 125 To 140
    Data(i) = Mid(shSource, location, 6)
    location = location + 6
Next i

'Print one row

For i = 1 To 140
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows + 1, i).Value = Data(i)
Next i

Next Rows


End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can likely speed up your code by turning off `ScreenUpdating` and setting `Application.Calculation` to manual (don't forget to reset to Auto when done!)  Also (1) you're reding the input cell value 140 times for each loop: read the value into a variable and then run your `Mid()` calls on that variable  (2) When assigning the array to the sheet you can do this: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows + 1, 1)Resize(1,140).Value = Data`  (no need to loop)

Comment: Thanks Tim! It cut the runtime down to 2.5 minutes. I wonder if there would be anything else I could do to speed it up with the screenupdating and manual calculation. The Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows + 1, 1)Resize(1,140).Value = Data however comes up as an error. Does that work with static arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely speed up your code by turning off ScreenUpdating and setting Application.Calculation to manual (don't forget to reset to Auto when done!)

Also

(1) you're reading the input cell value 140 times for each loop: faster to read the value into a variable, and then run your `Mid()` calls on that variable

```
Dim v As String
v = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows, 1).Value
Data(1) = "00" + Mid(v, 1, 2)
'etc
```

(2) When assigning the array to the sheet you can do it in one line this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows + 1, 1).Resize(1, 140).Value = Data
```

(no need to loop)

A more advanced approach would be to do everyting in memory using arrays, but I first would try the steps above and see what kind of improvement you get.

Comment: Thanks Tim! This cut down the running time to almost nothing.